# HTML5 Canvas - unwanted image URL exposing

Tags: html, image, url, canvas

HTML5 Canvas is great, but I don't feel good about exposing images URLs.

```
image.src = "image.png";
```

I don't want visitors see that URL (which can be found when visitor displays site source) a let him download it.

What should I do?

Comment: There's nothing you can do, to put it in the canvas (or anywhere else), the visitor has to download it. That's how client-side tech works.

Comment: you could use a dataurl which unless they know what they're doing would be kinda useless to them but as @peachykeen said they have to have public access to it. If that is sufficient let me know and I'll post sample.

Comment: Even if you disallow viewing the url, I can simply take screenshot of the image and copy it. What are you trying to achieve with this? You can however put licensing on images that makes it illegal to use without permission

Comment: So it's time to learn Rails, mm?

Comment: Not to mention tools like Firebug and Chrome Tools...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put a clear image over your prized image so users can't just right-click+saveImageAs.

You can subtly watermark your images to make them less attractive to steal.

You could break the image into multiple sections that appear unified on the screen.  That makes the thief work harder to reassemble your whole image.

You can use ajax to download the image in base64 encoded form and restrict access to that server url.

Put low resolution images on your site and let appropriate users get high resolution images via secured download.

Just let people use your images freely and accumulate the Karma points--or host ads on your site so you get bucks for views.

Put a clearly visible legal restriction on the use of your images and follow up if someone is reselling your images.

But quite frankly there is no defense against image theft:  Alt+PrintScreen + Paint+Paste == your image is stolen.

Answer (score 3):

You can take steps to obscure it with Javascript, so that the user has to dig a little to find the src. But there is no way to hide it.

I'm guessing that you are coming from Flash where image urls are hidden in a binary .swf file or embedded directly in the .swf. But even in that case, advanced users can parse the binary to locate the urls or extract the images.

The internet was designed to be open.

Comment: To obfuscate: http://javascriptobfuscator.com - but it's easily deobfuscated with http://jsbeautifier.org

Comment: It's just as easy to start firebug and watch the obfusicated javascript or flash make the request and then grab the URL.